# InjectTouchInput() function and POINTER_TOUCH_INFO members

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, touch, windows-8.1

I have wrapped Windows API touch functions into my wrapper classes and am successfully able to inject touch. To specify the touch coordinates I am using "ptPixelLocation" member of POINTER_TOUCH_INFO struct. So, like this:

```
POINTER_TOUCH_INFO pTouchInfo;
memset(&pTouchInfo, 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));
pTouchInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = myDesiredX;
pTouchInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = myDesiredY;
```

This works fine and I am able to successfully inject touch into both of my touch-screen monitors. However, some features (e.g. Windows Charms bar), do not work when I have BOTH touch monitors on and the desktop extended. But when I switch the ONE monitor only, or when I duplicate the desktop on BOTH screens, Charms bar STARTS to work.

This makes me think that maybe I should use "ptPixelLocationRaw", instead of "ptPixelLocation" to specify touch location. The question is WHAT DO WE UNDERSTAND BY RAW COORDINATES and WHAT SHOULD THEY BE IN RELATION TO (0,0), which is the UPPER LEFT CORNER OF THE MAIN MONITOR.

So, ideally, I would like to see this code working:

```
POINTER_TOUCH_INFO pTouchInfo;
memset(&pTouchInfo, 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));
pTouchInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocationRaw.x = myDesiredX;//after some conversion
pTouchInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocationRaw.y = myDesiredY;//after some conversion
```

Does anyone know what do we mean by RAW COORDINATES?

Comment: From the [`POINTER_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454907.aspx) documentation: *"**ptPixelLocationRaw**: The screen coordinates of the pointer, in pixels."* Screen coordinates are explained at [Window Coordinate System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145205.aspx). The distinction between raw and adjusted coordinates is relevant only when **receiving** a `POINTER_INFO` structure by [`GetPointerInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454885.aspx) in response to a `WM_POINTERDOWN` message, for example, not when **sending** it.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the clarification. I think I am at a point where I can't move any forward due to a bug Win 8.1. Currently talking to MS to solve the issue

Comment: @IInspectable, could you please answer the question, instead of adding it as comment? I answered it myself by referring to your comment and people have voted my answer down because of that.